# how to set canvas size on inputted height and width in my image editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

below are the code and link of my image editor.  I want to set selection area size on height and width enter by user. 
For ex. 
if user enter width 300 and height 200, selection size change at this size. Also how to add minimum size as 200*200

please have a look at this link - http://lifestylewallart.com.au/imageeditor/index.php?pId=2

I have only included necessary code here.

```html
`<?php require_once '../app/Mage.php';

Mage::app(); 
$pId = $_REQUEST['pId'];

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pId);  
$buy = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
$imgUrl = $_product->getImageUrl();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="A basic demo of Cropper.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JS, JavaScript, jQuery plugin, image cropping, image crop, image move, image zoom, image rotate, image scale, front-end, frontend, web development">
  <meta name="author" content="Fengyuan Chen">
  <title>Editor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/tooltip.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/cropper.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  var myResult = [(myBox1 * myBox2 * 0.69)/100];
  result.value = parseFloat(myResult).toFixed(2);
  
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- header -->
  <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top docs-header" id="top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0);">Image Editor</a>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <!-- <h3 class="page-header">Demo:</h3> -->
        
 <div class="imageDiv original">
         <div class="img-container">
            <img src="<?php echo $imgUrl;?>" alt="Picture">
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<h3 class="page-header">Price Calculator </h3> 
        <div class="docs-data">
     <form name="pricecalculator" id="pricecalculator" method="post" action="<?php echo $buy;?>"/>
    <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="dataWidth">Width</label>
            <input id="box1" type="text" onchange="calculate()"/>
   <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataWidth" placeholder="width"> --> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="dataHeight">Height</label>
   <input id="box2" type="text" onchange="calculate()"/>
            <!--  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataHeight" placeholder="height"> --> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
          </div>
    <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="dataHeight">Total Price</label>
    
    
   <input id="result" type="text" readonly="readonly" onchange="calculate()"/>
              <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataHeight" placeholder="height"> --> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">AUD</span>
          </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="pId" id="pId" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['pId'];?>" /> 
    <input type="button" name="addtocart" id="addtocart" value="Proceed to Checkout"/> 
    
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/tooltip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/cropper.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#addtocart" ).click(function() {
   calculate();
   var width = $('#box1').val();
   var height = $('#box2').val();
   var price = $('#result').val();
   var pId = $('#pId').val();
   $.post( "addtocart.php", { width:width , height:height , price:price ,pId:pId})
     .done(function( data ) {
    $( "#pricecalculator" ).submit();
   });
  });
 });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
`
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can use the `type="number"` attribute and its related attributes like `min="200"` to limit what can be entered here (HTML5 only). I'm unsure what you mean with the 'selection'.

Comment: here is the example -http://www.pickawall.com.au/mywall/artwork/step2/  please check this link and step that after entering height and width, on next step it sets canvas to that size only

Comment: On stack overflow we can be helpful to fix or help you reach your answer, but we are not here to build it for you. Try to build it yourself and return when issues crop up. Read up on canvas and have a look at their code.

Comment: Hi I am not able to see your previous answer for this post .. did you delete it ??

Comment: Yes i did as your comment made it look irrelevant. I have undeleted it.

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm correct you are trying to simply display the multiple of two numbers in a third space, while also checking that number does not exceed or is below a certain number. The code below is a simplified implementation (there are better ways than using an id do to do this, but for the sake of the example this is quite easy):

```js
var sizeWidth = document.getElementById("size-width");
var sizeHeight = document.getElementById("size-height");
var sizeSubmit = document.getElementById("size-submit");
var sizeResult = document.getElementById("size-result");

function evaluateSize(){
  var surface = sizeWidth.value * sizeHeight.value;
  sizeResult.textContent = surface;
  if(surface > 2 && surface < 30){
    sizeSubmit.removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    sizeSubmit.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  }
}

sizeWidth.addEventListener("keyup", evaluateSize, false);
sizeHeight.addEventListener("keyup", evaluateSize, false);
```

```html
<form id="size">
  <input type="number" id="size-width" />  
  <input type="number" id="size-height" />
  <p><span id="size-result">0</span> Sqm (min 2, max 30)</p>
  <input type="submit" id="size-submit" disabled /> 
</form>
```

I have noticed that you ask people to enter in centimeters but the result is in square meters, this is confusing. Be consistent with your units of measurement! Since you are having the `,` there anyway, make it all centimetres! It means you can also omit any REMINDER messages.

Setting your canvas as such is a different question altogether. You are not looking to set the canvas to a certain width, you are looking to set the canvas and some transparent content area...

Comment: hi please have a look here http://www.pickawall.com.au/mywall/artwork/step2/ . i want to reate like this and at next step at   edit image tab it should set area as per width and height size ..